# Div's appearing different (Firefox vs Internet Explorer)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a footer which is included in `register.php`, ( a simple registration page. )

The footer includes a text section to the right and a error reporting section to the left.

My issue is Internet Explorer does not display my code the same way Firefox does. Here are some examples:

**Firefox:**
[image: Firefox]

**Internet Explorer:**
[image]

Here is my CSS for the left side ( error reporting ):

```
 #errors
{
float:left;
margin-left:4.5%;
text-align:left;
color:red;
}
```

Here is my CSS for the right side ( text area ):

```
#footer p
{
text-align:right;
margin-right:3%; 
}
```

And, finally here is my CSS for the entire footer:

```
#footer
{
width:100%;
border-top:1px solid black;  
bottom:0;
color:#838B8B;
font-family:verdana;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well, so that we can see what precisely your CSS is targeting?

Comment: It kind of looks like the red text is being restricted by width in some way, although I can't see anything in your CSS that would cause that. Try looking at all CSS properties applied to your #errors element via Developer Tools (not just the one rule). Also: Given that the width seems to match up with the inputs above (although there should be no relevance between them) try putting your page through the W3C Validator to see if you have any unclosed tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but you could try:

```
#errors
{
float:left;
margin-left:4.5%;
text-align:left;
color:red;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```